# GZIP Compression Issue

Tags: php, flash

I've written a SWF distributor which GZIPs the SWF then sends it as an SWF content type, it works just if the SWF used to loop it no longer does.
Anyone know any reason why the compressed SWF doesn't loop the video/animation?

Comment: What does this have to do with php?

Comment: It only happens after the PHP has applied GZIP compression, so my guess is it's something to do with that. That's what it has to do with PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the `Content-Type` header, do you also send `Content-Encoding: gzip`?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to GZIP SWFs.

They are by default already compressed files.

Gzip prevents the SWF from streaming. In the sense that.... totalBytes is 0. It causes most SWF files to fail to load or other nasty problems.

Look at htaccess and turn off gzip for swfs/video/sound